# ms sql query for looping through table data and add 1 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
Id      Start time          End time
1       18-09-2014 02:12        18-09-2014 02:18
2       18-09-2014 05:20        18-09-2014 05:26
```

After execution of a query I got the result as above. From the above data I need to get the data as below by adding 1 minute to the start time up to the end time and need to store the same to a temporary table.

```
            Time
    18-09-2014 02:12
    18-09-2014 02:13
    18-09-2014 02:14
    18-09-2014 02:15
    18-09-2014 02:16
    18-09-2014 02:17
    18-09-2014 02:18

    18-09-2014 05:20
    18-09-2014 05:21
    18-09-2014 05:22
    18-09-2014 05:23
    18-09-2014 05:24
    18-09-2014 05:25
    18-09-2014 05:26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
Declare @starttime datetime = '2012-09-09 02:12:00'
Declare @endtime datetime = '2012-09-09 02:33:00'

create table temp(starttime datetime)

WHILE @starttime <= @endtime
 BEGIN     

    insert into temp values(@starttime)
    SET @starttime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @starttime)
 END

select * from temp

drop table temp
```